# Common solution for initializing const member variable in abstract base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Given the following situation

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(double par1, double par2)
        :
        par1_(par1),
        par2_(par2)
        {}

    const double value_;

protected:
    const double par1_, par2_;
    virtual double Calc_Value() = 0;
};


class Derived_A : public Base
{
public:
    Derived_A(double par1, double par2)
        :
        Base(par1, par2)
        {}
  
protected:
    double Calc_Value()
        {
            // <code to calc value with par1_ and par2_>
        }
};


class Derived_B : public Base
{
public:
    Derived_B(double par1, double par2, double par3)
        :
        Base(par1, par2),
        par3_(par3)
        {}

    const double par3_;

protected:
    double Calc_Value()
        {
            // <code to calc value with par1_, par2_ and par3_>
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> my_vector;
    // do stuff using polymorphism
}
```

This has been bugging me for some time. I would like to initialize `value_` with `Calc_Value()` when creating an object of `Derived_A` or `Derived_B`. I know that only `Base`
can initialize its **const** members. Now, my class objects  are mostly some sort of containers which calculate the necessary values when they are created. So they should be read only.
I know I could make `value_` not **const**, but that would make it mutable. Most solutions I found in the internet is just to create an additional constructor in `Base` but then I would have to declare `par3_` in the base class which means, every time there is a `derived_A` object it will have a `par3_` member variable without ever using it. Also, imagine I want to have more Derived classes with  different `Calc_Value()` functions, do I then need to declare a constructor for every additional subclass? So far, I have overcome this problem with just making the `Calc_Value()` function **public** and therefore there was no need for a **public const**  member variable. But when accessing the object via a function, the round brackets reduce readability in my opinion, which is why I would like to have a **const** member variable in `Base`.

Is there a common solution to this problem?

Comment: If it's `const` it must be initialized in the constructor initializer list.

Comment: If the value of `value_` is only known by the derived class, why is it a member of the base class? You could for example have a pure virtual `getValue` function in `Base` and let the derived class supply the value.

Comment: Note that to correctly use polymorphism you need to define a virtual destructor in your base class.

Comment: @super `value_` of base needs to contain the calculated value, otherwise `myvector[idx]->value_` won't work or what do you mean? Also, do you mean a pure virtual function like `Calc_Value()` but public? I did that but the round brackets reduce readability in my opinion which why I would like to have a **const** member. I was just wondering if there was a solution which I am not aware of. I am not an experienced coder.

Comment: @Andi You can't have both the value stored in the base class, and it being const, and it being calculated in the derived class. You could as an alternative store `value_` in the derived class and use `myvector[idx]->getValue()` to get it.

Comment: @super Alright, than I'll stick to the get-functions, thanks!

Comment: @anastaciu Thanks for the comments! I guess, what I wanted to do is not possible. And yes, I forgot the destructor in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a `const double&` in your base class and store the double in your derived class. Something like this.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo(const double& ref) : value(ref) {}
    const double& value;
};

struct Bar : Foo {
    Bar(const double p1, const double p2) : Foo (value), value(p1 + p2) {}

    private:
    double value;
};

int main() {
    Bar b(5, 3);

    Foo* f = &b;

    std::cout << f->value;
}
```

Here `Bar` is allowed to modify `value`, but since `Base` has a const ref you can't modify the value using the reference.

If you need `Bar::value` to be `const` as well, you would need to initialize it in the constructor initializer list. If you additionally require a function to calculate that value it can't be a member function, since you can't call a member function before the object has been constructed.

In that case you could make `Calc_value` a static member function and pass it the parameters it needs from the constructor of `Bar`

```
struct Bar : Foo {
    Bar(const double p1, const double p2) : Foo (value), value(Calc_value(p1, p2)) {}

    private:
    static double Calc_value(const double p1, const double p2) {
        return p1 + p2;
    }
    double value;
};
```

It just seems like you are making you code a bit overly complicated just to avoid writing `()` at this point.